# Nginx + Android HTTPS/TLS Very Slow

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, https

I am using the following Nginx configuration which is working fine from every device except for Android devices. From android devices the connection usually ends with a timeout connection from both the chrome browser and an Android App. I have Nexus 6 and the server is hosted on Amazon EC2.

I am on WiFi and all other devices on the same WiFi network work perfectly fine.

```
upstream serverName {
    server localhost:8080;
}

upstream serverName2 {
    server serverName2.companyName.co:19001;
}


server {
    listen      80 default;
    server_name localhost api.companyName.co;
    return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl spdy;
    server_name localhost companyName.co;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate          /etc/nginx/ssl/crt_file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key      /etc/nginx/ssl/key_file.key;

    ssl_stapling             on;
    ssl_stapling_verify      on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/ssl/ca-certs.pem;

    add_header  X-Frame-Options            "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header  X-Content-Type-Options     "nosniff";
    add_header  X-XSS-Protection           "1; mode=block";
    add_header  Strict-Transport-Security  "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    location / {
        return 302 /api;
    }

    location /api {
        include             snippets/proxy_pass.conf;
        proxy_pass          http://serverName;
        proxy_send_timeout  15;
        proxy_read_timeout  20;
    }

    location = /api/documents {
        include               snippets/proxy_pass.conf;
        proxy_pass            http://serverName;
        proxy_read_timeout    180s;
        proxy_send_timeout    300s;

        client_max_body_size  100M;
    }

    location = /ws-comm {
        include             snippets/proxy_pass.conf;
        proxy_pass          http://serverName2;
        proxy_send_timeout  7d;
        proxy_read_timeout  7d;

        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```